# Create multiple site in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

Is there is a way in liferay to create 2 site say hr.example.com and sales.example.com in the example.com . Whenever a user logs in then corresponding to the user roles can we redirect him to hr or sales site and example.com to the normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use virtual hosting concept of Liferay, see

http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Virtual+Hosting+%28Communities%29

note: "Community" is "Site" since Liferay 6.1

Answer (score 0):

See Site Settings > Virtual Hosts option to map your Site with some URL.

In order to redirect user based on his role, create post login hook with PostLoginAction.java, and do role check in that class and redirect based on role.

Basically override login.events.post property in your hook and provide implementation in PostLoginAction .

Marketplace App can be helpful to you: [Custom Landing Page Hook](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/17676547)